# Testing a Redux login Action

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, redux

I'm hoping that I could ask for some help on how to test a Redux Action that involves a login API call. I've looked at some examples of testing an async Action, but I haven't wrapped my head around how to test the code below.

As a starting point, I would like to test that a)`AUTH_USER` is called if the `.post` request returns a `200 and b)`localStorage` contains the token from the API call.

I've looked at using `redux-mock-store`, `fetch-mock` and `isomorphic-fetch` in order to mock the API calls to make sure I always receive the expected API response, but I have no idea where to start with the test.

Any help would be highly appreciated on a starting point for the tests! Even some help on just testing that `200` will return `AUTH_USER` would be appreciated!

*Note: Elsewhere for other tests I'm using, redux-mock-store, enzyme, chai, expect, fetch-mock, isomorphic-fetch*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { API_URL } from 'config';
import {
  AUTH_USER
} from './types';

export function loginUser({ email, password }) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { email, password })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/feature');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'));
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: What javascript test framework you use?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Enzyme, chai, expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Async Test Motivation**

We want to ensure that a AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS action is dispatched by our redux thunk middleware if the login is successful a AUTHENTICATION_FAILED action if the log in fails.

Remember we are not testing the Redux Thunk middleware, instead we are only testing our Thunk Action creator.

**Testing a Redux Thunk action creator which queries an API**

1. Create a mock store for each unit test with redux-thunk middleware
2. Use a mocking library such as nock to intercept http requests to test which actions are dispatched for a given type of request. Since we are testing a login request obvious cases here are http responses signalling login success and failure.
3. Verify the correct action was dispatched to the store for a given http response.

**Example**

*Tests*

Here is an example of two tests for login success and failure using nock to mock the api call and the expect library for test assertions.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import nock from 'nock'
import expect from 'expect' // You can use any testing library

// modify these imports to suit your project
import * as actions from '../../actions/TodoActions' 
import * as types from '../../constants/ActionTypes'

import {
  AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR
} from './types';

const API_URL = 'www.api-example.com'
const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll()
  })

  it('creates AUTH_USER action when user is logged in', () => {
    nock(API_URL)
      .post(/auth/login)
      .reply(200, { data: 'Logged in successfully'] }})

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: AUTH_USER }
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ })

    return store.dispatch(actions.loginUser({'example@x.com','password'}))
      .then(() => { // return of async actions
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
      })
  })

  it('creates AUTH_ERROR if user login fails', () => {
    nock(API_URL)
      .post(/auth/login)
      .reply(404, { data: {error: 404 }] }})

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: AUTH_ERROR }
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ })

    return store.dispatch(actions.loginUser({'example@x.com','password'}))
      .then(() => { // return of async actions
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
      })
  })
})
```

Now to make the example work you need to add a return statement inside the function returned by your thunk action creator.

By eventually returning the promise given to us by axios.post we can add the .then call inside our test to make assertions about which actions have been dispatched *after* the promise has resolved.

*Thunk action creator*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { API_URL } from 'config';
import {
  AUTH_USER
} from './types';

export function loginUser({ email, password }) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { email, password })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/feature');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'));
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Great start I think! I seem to get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on the `.then` of `store.dispatch`. I put a log in the `loginUser` function and it's definitely receiving the email and password from the test. Any idea?

Comment: See my edit. You need to return the call to axios.post which will return a promise.

Comment: Thanks for that. Should I be using a real email/password for this test? Currently, I receive the `Bad Login Info` message when trying to test the `200` login request which isn't ideal. I thought a library like `nock` was to fake the request and make sure it always sends the response you define in the test file.

Comment: No, there would be no good reason to use a real password for this test. Remember we are using Nock to intercept the http request so it would have no idea if the username or password were correct anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought, I was just stuck as it always end up getting caught by the `.catch` function instead of getting to the `.then` and returning the Action.

Comment: Actually, I found that it was still hitting the API in the Action which is why it was getting stuck in the `.catch` function. Very strange.

Comment: You need to pass in the correct arguments to nock in the test in order to ensure that nock intercepts the correct request. Otherwise you will be hitting the real api which is not what we want.

Comment: Will mark this as the correct answer. Actually my error came from the fact that I was not specific enough with my question. It was still ending up in the `.catch` function because I was using `axios` for my API calls, and the tests were in Chrome/PhantomJS so the API calls were not being picked up. I had to install an axios mock library to detect the calls. Other than that the answer worked flawlessly so thanks a lot for the help.